# Accessing memory mapped registers in gdb

Tags: kernel, qemu, gdb

I'm trying to read (hopefully write as well) to the memory mapped hardware registers in a qemu virtual machine using gdb (remote connected). But it's just not working:

```
(gdb) p *0x2000000
Cannot access memory at address 0x20000000
```

But if I log in to the machine and do

```
# devmem 0x2000000
0xE321F0D3
```

This works fine. Clearly gdb isn't getting its info from `/dev/mem` though. I've enabled all compile-time debug flags that I could think of, I can place breakpoints, step through code and dereference pointers associated with a symbol just fine. But most raw pointer dereferences fail.

For the record this is how I launched qemu:

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -kernel output/images/zImage     \
                -dtb output/images/versatile-pb.dtb             \
                -drive file=output/images/rootfs.ext2,if=scsi   \
                -append "root=/dev/sda console=ttyAMA0,115200 nokaslr norandmaps printk.devkmsg=on printk.time=y"  \
                -nographic -s
```

where I added `nokaslr` etc because I thought it would make a difference. It clearly did not. Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

`gdb` and `devmem` are looking at two different things. `gdb` is looking at location `0x20000000` as *mapped* into your [process address space](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand007.html), which is different from process to process (it has to be, or else swap files and page tables would essentially be useless.) `devmem` is looking at the file `/dev/mem`, which looks directly at physical memory.

Why does process address space not expose all physical address locations to a process? The main reason is that it would be an enormous security breach: you don't want a random process to be able to read and write data from memory that they don't own (otherwise they could trivially bypass security.) Additionally, as [the `devmem` page puts it](https://github.com/pavel-a/devmemX/wiki/Using-devmem), "Some physical addresses are hardware registers; writing or even reading them can cause your computer/device [to] crash or melt down or explode. You've been warned!"